# XOR'ing arrays of chars

Tags: c, arrays, ascii, xor

I am a beginner to C programming and using devc. So I am trying to XOR one half of an array with the other half. I created one array of 3018 words which are taken as chars, and then try to XOR them. From looking around, I did as much as I can but it ain't working and neither do I understand exactly how to XOR..

If I have an array of 3018 numbers, i XOR the first 1509 numbers with the second 1509 numbers.. how can I do this??

```
int main(void)
{
int i = 0;
char message[3018] = {10, 117, 117, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10..}; 
char xor[1509];

    for(i=0; i<1510;i++)


xor[i] = (char)(message[i] ^ message[i+1509]);

// Enter your code here...

while(1);
return 0;
}
```

IMPORTANT: I cut off the

```
char message[3018] = {10, 117, 117, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10..};
```

line because there are obviously 3018 words that are inputted, I cannot show them all so I just used ...

there are some problems in the code above, for eg.
in the char message[3018] line, says unexpected unqualified id before xor token?
unexpected primary expression before 'xor' token in the xor[i] line..

Comment: Always define what "it ain't working" means. How doesn't it work? What is the result? What was expected? The only clear error in your code is the limits, i should go from 0 to 1508 for there to be 1509 values, so change 1510 to 1509 to fix that. Otherwise you are xoring chars correctly.

Comment: It's confusing when you mix "number" and "word". Often a "word" is a number of a particular size, like 16 bits, but that's not what you seem to mean. It's important to be precise with things like these.

Comment: sorry, the problem is to do with the char message[3018] line, says unexpected unqualified id before xor token?

Comment: Try renaming the xor[] array to somthing else. (maybe `xor` is a #define or alias for the `^` operator)

Comment: char message[3018] is dangours. This may lead to StackOverflow

Comment: If you're using a C++ compiler to compile C code, `xor` is a keyword. Use a different name for your array.

Comment: Instead of using magic numbers for array sizes, use constants or `#defines`. Would have saved you from this bug.

Comment: Whatever character set and encoding you are using (probably not ASCII [run `chcp`(Windows) or `locale`]), be careful that it makes sense to chop up a string into bytes, XOR them with other bytes and interpret the resulting bytes as a string. It would work with ASCII (values 0-127 are valid), CP437 (values 0-255 are valid), … but not Windows-1252 (has holes its code space), UTF-8 (doesn't split at every byte boundary and every byte sequence is not valid), …. Because of this, algorithms that twiddle bits typically give a byte array (numbers) as an output even if the input is a string (text).

Comment: @anony could you mark an answer here and update accordingly please

Answer (score 1):

Changing :

```
for(i=0;i<1510;i++)
   xor[i] = (char)(message[i] ^ message[i+1509]);
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<1509;i++)
  xor[i] = (char)(message[i] ^ message[i+1509]);
```

should provide you a correct XOR output.

And converting those numbers to char might result in unknown output characters for e.g. `k Xr2` was what I got for input `char message[10] = {10, 117, 117, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 90, 4};`. I hope you know what you are doing with them.

AND can we have some other array name instead,please :)
replace all `xor` by `xyznotkeyword`

Comment: sorry, i should have said one of the problem was the char xor[1509] initialising line, there is an unexpected unqualified id before xor token